# How to add a table to a NS/UITextView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, uiview, nsview

I can see in Apple Notes and other notes app that they have tables embedded into the text editor. Swift has [NSTextTable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstexttable), but it's just available for macOS. I'm wondering how I can add a table to both, macOS and iOS?

In addition, these tables should be interactive like in Apple Notes, like I can add a row or column, move them around, etc. I have seen [this project](https://github.com/vlas-voloshin/SubviewAttachingTextView) which enables you to embed a NS/UIView into the editor, but this seems more like a hack.

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of using TextView, you can try with UIScrollView.

Comment: How would I accommodate the text view? Or you mean splitting it up: TextView - Table - TextView, all wrapped in a Scrollview?

Comment: You can add all the components in UIScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is no simple way to add such attachments to a textView on iOS, you may try to find something in NSAttributedString, but probably it won't have a solution, so https://github.com/vlas-voloshin/SubviewAttachingTextView looks like a good option.